# Взаимодействие приложения на C++ и PHP-сервера

Tags: php, c++

Помогите пожалуйста выйти из творческого тупика:

Приложение на C++ при старте сверяет свою версию с информацией о последней версии, которая хранится в базе данных на хостинге.

Как на PHP вернуть информацию приложению (ведь это не браузер)? А так же какой должен быть минимальный набор параметров в заголовке POST-запроса при отправке на сервер (клиент отправляет номер версии и её описание)?

Comment: Софтина GET-запросом получает с server.com\currentversion.php номер версии строкой типа "7.00.123456". Вот, в общем-то, и все.

Comment: В PHP как ответ дать в сеть? Просто echo $Version или как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написал класс-обёртку https://github.com/sitev/cjWinHttp, чтобы обращаться из программы на С++ к сайтам, может и Вам пригодится =)

Comment: Спасибо! Узнал что есть WinHTTP кроме сокетов... Но вопрос по PHP всё ещё открыт - как в PHP-скрипте вернуть приложению (не браузеру) значение? Простого echo будет достаточно или нет?

Comment: Да, конечно же достаточно!

Answer (score 0):

Один из возможных вариантов:
Программа на С++ делает http-запрос к php скрипту. PHP скрипт выполняет нужные манипуляции с базой данных, формирует ответ и отправляет его в формате json(xml). Программа на С++ получает этот ответ и парсит json(xml) в удобный для использования вид.

Comment: Ну да, такой сценарий и планируется, правда без json - просто надо вернуть строку "Run" или "Close"  ( "1" или "0") чтобы клиент либо запустился либо вывел MessageBox "Надо обновиться" и закрылся. Как из PHP вернуть в приложение - просто echo, или нет?